# Instantiating Singleton class with CLLocationManager in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, singleton, cllocation

i am using a singleton class to track a users location. if i instantiate the class from within my running app and start tracking everything is peachy.

however, if the app is closed (in the app switcher so it isn't backgrounded any more) and restarted i check if there is an active event. in this case i instantiate the class and start the location tracking. the `locationManager` gets instantiated and the location arrow appears in the statusbar, but the

```
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
or 
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
never get called
```

any idea?

code singelton class:

```
@interface AlarmMeTrackUserLocation () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

@implementation AlarmMeTrackUserLocation    
-(void)toggleLocationUpdates:(bool)toggle {

    if (!toggle) {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager = nil;
        sharedInstance = nil;
        NSLog(@"--- UserTrack Stopped ---");
        return;
    }


    if (!self.locationManager && toggle) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200;
    }

    NSLog(@"--- UserTrack Started");
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    ...
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ...
}

+ (AlarmMeTrackUserLocation *)sharedTrackUserLocation {

    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];

        //NSLog(@"--- New Instance created ---");

        return sharedInstance;
    }

    NSLog(@"--- Existing Instance Used ---");

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

code from AppDelegate:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AlarmMeTrackUserLocation *userTrack;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    self.userTrack = [AlarmMeTrackUserLocation sharedTrackUserLocation];
    self.userTrack.event = currentEvent;
    [self.userTrack toggleLocationUpdates:YES];

}
```

Comment: "however, if the app is closed and restarted i check if there is an active event" There should be no need to do that. If the location manager was tracking when we went into the background, it will resume automatically when we come back into the foreground.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i meant when the app is closed in the app switcher, so it isn't backgrounded any more - clarified that in the question.

Comment: If the app is *killed* in the app switcher it is dead. In this case it is launching from a cold start. So you should now "instantiate the class from within my running app and start tracking everything is peachy" - in other words, the conditions are exactly the same in both cases. So you need to think about (and show) the code where you start tracking at launch and the code where you start tracking "within my running app". Whatever the difference is, that's the cause of the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after carefully reviewing my code i could only see one difference: in the app delegate i start a backgrounding thread to fetch data from a webserver. if the request is complete the singleton class is instantiated and locationManager is set (still in the background thread).

after switching back to the main thread and instantiating its finally working!

so it seems you cant delegate a CLLocationManager from a backgrounding thread

Comment: can you add some sample code as to how you got a block of your code on main thread? Did you use dispatch_async on your web service response?

Comment: I just saw your comment, sorry for the late response. This thread was from '13, unfortunately I don't have the code anymore